# Можно ли применять слово "хрупчать"?

Tags: выбор-слов

Существует слово "охрупчать", можно ли применять слово "хрупчать"? 
В произведениях прошлого века слово "хрупчать" встречается, но в словарях его нет...

Comment: Вы не могли бы привести примеры использования этих слов в произведениях прошлого века? Это интересно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Слово "хрупчать" мне встретилось у [Новеллы Матвеевой](https://public.wikireading.ru/177279):

*Тем усерднее говорить, что у меня это, кажется, неплохо получалось – особенно там, где "Не исчезай же!", – и жест был удачный! И про "дитя Бахуса"… А то ведь же и сознание начинало уже от невзгод **хрупчать**, – следовало срочно удержать его от этого необдуманного шага! Но чем ты удержишь...*

Возможно, слово употребляется в значении *ломаться (разламываться), трещать, трескаться, раскалываться, хрустеть.*

**Дополнение**
Мне кажется, что "хрупчать" по смыслу перекликается со словами:
[**хруп**](https://slovar.cc/rus/ushakov/466247.html) — в знач. сказуемого (разг.). Хрупнул. Стекло хруп под ногою;
[**хруптеть**](https://books.google.ee/books?id=8BCQAwAAQBAJ&pg=PT281&lpg=PT281&dq=%D1%85%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C&source=bl&ots=49DPYpreAl&sig=hM3F9ww_qwbQGyuRO6ScU0aP54Q&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwit4tuRju7ZAhWnFZoKHaRnB2wQ6AEIQDAE#v=onepage&q=%D1%85%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C&f=false) — ср. хрупаться и хрупнуть, хрептеть — издавать хруст, хрустеть, хрястнуть, треснуть (С. Есенин. Яр).

Если Вы вкладываете в слово "хрупчать" именно этот смысл, то, думаю, его вполне можно использовать (немаловажно, чтобы Вас поняли).

**Дополнение к дополнению**
Для меня слово "хрупчать" стало своеобразным открытием. Удивительно: словарного глагола нет, а производных — тьма:

*Гаэбам, видать, было невдомёк, что такой материал, как пластик, на морозе **хрупчает**.*
Журнал "Самиздат". Племя свободных

*— Вот и именно, — утвердительно махнул рукой Афанасий, —  достаётся ей в жизни бед…   горя… слёз  поболе,  чем радостей, а она только сильней становится. Не **хрупчает**, а крепчает и крепчает…*
В. Лызлова. Деревенская душа

*Сильных марсотрясений в округе Тарсис не бывает, поскольку здесь тектоника слабая, вулканы давно потухшие, хотя вследствие электрохимических и эрозионных процессов некоторые почвенные слои **хрупчают** и оседают*.
А. Тюрин. Меч космонавта

Comment: _Возможно, слово употребляется в значении ломаться_ Я думаю, что это слово значит просто "становиться более хрупким" (ср. "хрупче" — более хрупкий).

Comment: Именно так: становиться более хрупким. Посмотрите переписку в социальных сетях. Вот отзыв на крем для рук и ногтей: "...домашнюю работу как-то уборка, стирка, мытье посуды я делаю голыми руками. За что потом и несу заслуженную кару – когти начинают **хрупчать** и слоиться..."

Comment: Похоже на аналогию "крепкий-крепчать / хрупкий-хрупчать". В. Лызлова - [коренная северянка](https://ridero.ru/books/prosto_zhit_1/) (Ухта).

Comment: @alexsms Да, вполне вероятно. Но словарного глагола нет, поэтому возникают "свободные" словоформы, например: _А теперь придётся держать кружку над короткой осиновой спичкой, которая, обугливаясь, изгибается, **хрупчеет**, жжётся._

Comment: словарного нет, в этом и интерес. Похоже, в народе они и возникают (в Архангельской обл. даже зафиксировано).

Answer (score 0):

Google.books [находит слово "хрупчать"](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b&biw=1047&bih=481&tbm=bks&ei=vEKqWu7JEq7b6QSl9oXYCw&q=%D1%85%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C&oq=%D1%85%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C&gs_l=psy-ab.12...10572.10572.0.12050.1.1.0.0.0.0.153.153.0j1.1.0....0...1c..64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.K2FaV_qcgyY) в "Обратном словаре архангельских говоров" О.Г.Гецовой. Следовательно, это слово диалектное, и всё зависит от того, где и в каком контексте Вы хотели бы его использовать. (Подозреваю, что слово "охрупчать" не менее диалектное.)

Comment: В технике есть понятие "охрупчивание" материала (переход из вязкого состояния к хрупкому), соотв. глагол - _охрупчиваться_.

Comment: Точно, спасибо! Я не слышал раньше, а сам не догадался поискать более правдоподобные словоформы.